# What are polytene bands, and why are they there?

Tags: genetics, cytogenetics, drosophila

*Drosophila* [polytene chromosomes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytene_chromosome) have been particularly useful in genetic research, as it made cytogenetic gene mapping possible with very little effort. This was primarily accomplished due to polytene bands, which are naturally-occuring (no stain) fixed bands seen along the chromosomes via microscopy.

We have been exploiting these bands for decades, but it seems as though their function isn't quite clear.

**What is the cause of the visible polytene bands, and what function do they serve?**

Comment: well, Wikipedia says that they are formed by numerous rounds of replication without cell division, and their function may be in gene dosage [but this is not really clear].  However, this is all without proper references, so you should probably wait until someone comes along with citations to verify.

Comment: [This review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=15548421) has more information than you will ever want to know.